# Dell r710 Temperature return empty and Fan speed stuck at lowest rate

Tags: dell-poweredge, fan

For some reason , my server is experiencing a weird issue which the fan is not bumping up to the max speed, but instead at a low rate of ~2760rpm . And also, when I check for the temperature at IDRAC web interface, it returns nothing (empty table). The server now is still running, but the fan speed is constant slow regardless of the ambient temperature and cpu temperature, and this has made the server at a dangerously high temperature (like 75C inside the case). I'm pretty scared that this will break the server some day

[The temperature returns nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l358T.jpg)

[Fan keeping at ~2760rpm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rArZw.jpg)

I suspect it is a problem with the temperature and causing this problem, so

1. How could I fix the problem of idrac returning nothing in temperature section?
2. If this problem can't be fixed easily, then is there any method to adjust the fan speed manually?

Comment: Is the idrac up to date ? If not, first thing to do.

Comment: Have you contacted Dell support?

Comment: @sfk is it actually matters? since that thing was working previously without any issue, and i suppose it wont suddenly stop working because the version is not update...

Comment: @HopelessN00b The warranty is over